# How do I undo accidental GIT revert from a branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-extensions

I accidentally reverted a commit that was unrelated to my my work from my local feature branch.  I have pushed my changes up to my feature branch and was about to issue a pull request to have my code reviewed and I can see that there are a whole load of unrelated changes which are due to the revert I did.

I can see the id of the commit that I reverted in BitBucket and just want to know what the easiest way is to undo the revert and pull the commit back into my branch.

I could take a new branch from development and then go through the process of manually merging my actual changes back into the new feature branch, but I suspect there is a much simpler action.

Just for reference, all of the fetch, pull and push are done through GIT Extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do a git revert another commit is created, revert the revert commit.

Comment: Can you do this even though I have pushed the changes to the remote branch and have been committing and pushing changes since I accidentally did the revert?

Comment: Yes you can still find the commit and revert it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple just reset to that commit.

```
git reset --hard <commit_id>
```

Or

```
git cherry-pick <commit_id> # If you have other commits over it
```

Comment: That would only work if they haven't continued to work on top of the branch after the revert.

Comment: I have continued to work on the branch after I did the revert.

Comment: So just follow the second solution and cherry pick the single commit.

Comment: Ok.  git cherry-pick looks like it could be the savior.  Just one question.  If I take the colleagues commit from the origin/develop branch which is our master dev branch for the whole project when I then push the changes to my origin/feature branch will git detect that the changes are not already on dev and therefore ignore them?